# What is the meaning of this statement about complex structure?

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

I get confused when in papers it is said that:

> "Something is holomorphic (Complex, symplectic, etc ...) in some Complex structure"

What is the meaning of this in general?

For example in a paper contains stuff about Hyper-Kahler manifold $\mathcal{M}$, it is mentioned that:

> $w_3$ (one of the Kahler forms of $\mathcal{M}$) is $(1,1)$ form in complex structure $J_3$ (one of the three complex structures relative to which $\mathcal{M}$ is hyper-Kahler)

or

> $\omega$ is a $(2,0)$ form in complex structure $J^{\zeta}$ ($\zeta$ is a coordinate on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ that parameterizes complex structures $J^{\zeta}$ relative to which $\mathcal{M}$ is Kahler)

Comment: Dear @MichaelAlbanese, I clicked two times previously, now I fixed it. sorry for inconvenience! just I had another question: what is the meaning of "R"(reals) below tensor product notation in your answer and What is the meaning if I replaced it with say "Z"(integers)?

Comment: It means the tensor product of $T^*M$ and $C$ as real objects. This is called the [complexification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, So I suppose that $A \bigotimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$ means that we consider $A$ and $B$ (or their elements) as **Integers**. Right?

Comment: We don't consider the elements as integers, because they aren't. Instead we consider $A$ and $B$ as abelian groups (more precisely, $\mathbb{Z}$-modules).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, So $\Gamma^* \bigotimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{C}^*$ in which $\Gamma^*$ is _dual lattice_ and $\mathbb{C}^*$ is Riemann sphere or $\mathbb{CP}^1$, is tensor product of two $\mathbb{Z}$-module which is an $r$-dimensional complex torus if rank of lattice is $r$, Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *complex manifold* is a topological manifold equipped with an equivalence class of atlases consisting of charts which have holomorphic transition functions.

An *almost complex manifold* is a pair $(M, J)$ where $M$ is a smooth manifold and $J$ is a bundle endomorphism $J : TM \to TM$ with $J\circ J = -\operatorname{id}_{TM}$; we call $J$ an *almost complex structure*.

Every complex manifold admits a natural almost complex structure, but not every almost complex structure comes from a complex manifold; those which do are called *integrable*. Integrability can be characterised in several ways, the most common is by the vanishing of the Nijenhuis tensor - this is the content of the Newlander-Nirenberg Theorem.

Therefore, one can consider a complex manifold to be a smooth manifold $M$ equipped with an integrable almost complex structure $J$. In this way, $J$ determines the complex structure (and is sometimes just called the complex structure).

So to say an object has some property with respect to (or 'in') $J$ means that the object, when considered as an object on the complex manifold determined by $J$, has the stated property.

For example, in your second statement, $\omega$ is a two form on $M$ (the base manifold), so it is a section of $\bigwedge^2(T^*M\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C})$. In order to determine it's decomposition into $(2, 0)$, $(1, 1)$, and $(0, 2)$ parts, you need to know how the bundle splits - this is determined by $J$ (in fact, this doesn't require $J$ to be integrable). What is being said is that using the splitting given by $J_3$, $\omega$ is $(2, 0)$-form, but for some other $J$, $\omega$ may not be a $(2, 0)$-form.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is really helpful!